# Show just cursor (caret) but hide the letters in input

Tags: css

Is there a css way to show a cursor in a transparent input? I keep googling and all that pops up is how to hide it!

```
<input class='transparent' />

.transparent{
 color:transparent;
 background:transparent;
}
```

To be absolutely clear the only thing I want to show up in the input is the cursor, nothing else - i.e. the text should be hidden but the cursor should still be visible.

Comment: what about after typing in the input?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're after. Like this https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/gLjt2xmx/?

Comment: Input:hover{cursor:default}; Is this you are expecting?

Comment: Just curious, what is the purpose of such an input box? Maybe knowing the reason could help in suggesting alternates.

Comment: May be @j08691 is correct

Comment: @Harry I didn't put the reason because there are no alternatives. If you need to know then I have an input on top of an input to mask data.

Comment: @j08691 The color has to be transparent.

Comment: The color of what has to be transparent?

Comment: @j08691 Of the text being imputed into the field

Comment: @frnt In other words, caret.

Comment: @nicael Thank you :) That is correct

Comment: @j08691 And then the cursor disappears. :)

Comment: Something like this one input:hover{
cursor:default;
color:transparent;
}

Comment: In webkit only i think: https://jsfiddle.net/sztyefuu/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could style the text not touching the caret using the `text-fill-color` feature of webkit.

```css
 .transparent{
   background:transparent;
   color:black;   /* sets the color of both caret and text */
   -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent; /* sets just the text color */
 }
```

```html
<input class='transparent' />
```

The feature isn't supported by all the browsers, but the recent versions of the most widely-used browsers do support it.

Comment: I think OP wants to hide text as well

Comment: @zaz Looks like it won't, IE would probably require a more complex solution, I'll have a look.

Comment: @zaz Although [seems it will](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn985709(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Thank you so very much! You solved a conundrum that I have been trying to solve for a few days now!

Comment: Firefox seems like a regular input

Comment: @dippas Sorry, the comments I've added in the code messed up with it, now works!

Comment: still seems like a regular one

Comment: @dippas Huh, maybe you should upgrade your Firefox? Because Firefox supports that starting from 48 version.

Comment: @dippas Weird, I supposed it does, since I found the docs on mozilla org and it does work for Safari.

Comment: @dip Doesn't seem accurate since [it works with IE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn985709(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: When the text in the box is marked, the text become visible.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to solve this using the `caret-color` CSS property in input, text areas and content-editable divs:
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/caret-color/

```
input,
textarea,
[contenteditable] {
  caret-color: red;
}
```

Keep the color property as `transparent` for the text.